# Troubleshooting JVM heap size setting not propagating to application

Tags: java, web, jvm

Say that you have a Windows client where you have configured the JVM through javacpl.exe to have a larger maximum heap size, such as `-Xmx1024m`. If the application you are running (in a web browser) is still complaining that the memory size is not above `value Y`, a value that is hardcoded into the application to check, and we assume that we know that this check to be functional and correct, what steps can be taken to see why the app in question is not "getting" this modified heap size setting?

**edit** One possible cause of this is if you set a 32 bit JRE to more than 2 Gb (or so) of memory, as it will not handle it. 1024 should propagate, and my way of solving this was simply to disable different JRE's that I found on the system until I found out which one was being used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **verify** which **JVM arguments** are being passed into the VM during the startup.

- The easiest way to is to **run `jconsole`**, which will attach to the running VM and where you can see all the startup parameters, current Heap size, etc. jconsole comes with your VM distribution, you can find it in the JVM_HOME/bin/ directory already installed.
- another option is to **enable JVM logging** `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=jvm.log`, the jvm.log will again show all the startup scripts.

Also, try to set both `-Xmx` and `-Xms` to the same value, that way the initial Heap size will be your desired size.

Comment: `jconsole` is a part of the JDK, I forgot to mention that we are only dealing with the JRE here and there is no possibility to install the JDK. There is a console you can enable in the JRE settings, but that doesn't seem to give any useful information in regards to my question.

Comment: then, you can enable the logging. Also, in linux, you could do `ps -ef | grep <my_jvm-pid>` and this will also show you the startup parameters. You could also run jconsole on a different machine and attache remotely.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by logging, but the "console" can be enabled in the JRE which pops up a window with some info (among other things, the version), but no info about parameters is shown here.

Comment: By logging I meant the `-XX:LogFile=jvm.log` VM arguments that you pass when you start the VM.